Amazon S3 Bucket downloading excel file is corrupted
I uploaded and .xlsx into my Amazon S3 Bucket . The problem is when i am trying to retrieve it , the file is corrupted when i try to open it with Microsoft Excel. I am using AWS SDK for .NET.
The logic of downloading the file from the bucket :

public async Task<Stream?> DownloadFile(string s3Key)
    {
        try
        {
           
            var getFile = new GetObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = _bucketName,
                Key = s3Key
            };
            var response = await AmazonS3Client.GetObjectAsync(getFile);
            return response.ResponseStream;
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return null;
        }
    }


Than goes into my BUCKET SERVICE Layer

public async Task<Stream?> DownloadFile(string s3Key)
    {
        var getFileStream = await _bucketAcces.DownloadFile(s3Key);

        return getFileStream;

    }

Than into my ADMIN SERVICE LAYER:
 public Task<Stream?> GetExcelFile()
    {
        return _bucketService.DownloadFile("produseExcelExample.xlsx");
    }

Than into my controller:
public async Task<IActionResult> GetExcelFile()
        {
            var fileStream = await _adminService.GetExcelFile();
            if (fileStream is not null)
            {
                var fileMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                await fileStream.CopyToAsync(fileMemoryStream);
                fileMemoryStream.Position = 0;
                var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(fileMemoryStream,
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
                {
                    FileDownloadName = "Exemplu_excel.xlsx"
                };
                return fileStreamResult;
            }

            return NotFound("Error on downloading file");
        }

The file gets downloaded , everything is fine , but when i try to open it i get the corrupted file error:

And then

UPDATE
This is how i receive it on the frontend(forgot to mention this):
const downloadExcel = async () => {
    try {
        // Call the admin service to get the file
       
        const response =  await adminService.downloadExcel();
        
        // Convert the response into a Blob (binary large object)
        const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });

        // Create a URL for the blob object
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // Create an anchor element and set the href to the blob URL
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'exemplu_fisier.xlsx'); // Set the desired file name

        // Programmatically click the anchor to trigger the download
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();

        // Clean up by removing the anchor and revoking the object URL
        link.remove();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    } catch (error) {
        fireAlarm(showErrorFileDwonload);
        console.error("Error downloading Excel file:", error);
    }
}

I'm, using Vue.js 3 for the frontend
UPDATE 2

It has 10.77kB and the file i am downloading has 16.77kB. So something is not good when i retrieve it from the bucket, that s why it might be corrupted.
What to do here ?
UPDATE SOLVED
Such a rookie mistake i made. Of course the file was treated as JSON not Blob. Forgot to put blob in my responseType on the API request to the backend.

There's nothing obviously wrong with your code (except that you don't dispose fileStream, and I'm not sure why you copy it to a MemoryStream, but those shouldn't be causing corruption). Are you sure the file on S3 is not corrupt? Can you open the file in a hex editor, and see if there's anything obviously wrong with it (all 0's, or something)

Is the response.ResponseStream actually independent from the response when reading from it? Response gets out of scope and destroyed. And you use response.ResponseStream afterwards. Maybe, for a check, move the copying into a MemoryStream into the initial DownloadFile method and surface that.

@canton7 i just openede them and there is bunch of zeros on the corrupted one

Glad that you solved it! Please add your solution as an Answer so future readers can benefit from your learnings. (Or, if it was just a typo, feel free to delete the Question.)

The solution is : Forgot to put the response type blob when receiving the file to the frontend, instead it was treated like a JSON and that s why it appeared corrupted.
